# How to check the content of swap memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, swap, tmpfs

I am trying to find out what exactly uses swap memory in my system.
Free reports over 5GB of used swap memory, but all processes use only 24MB of swap.
I suspect that swap might be used by a tmpfs filesystem, but I don't know how to check it.

**Would you be so kind to tell what else should I check to examine content of the swap memory, please?**

```
    # free -m
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:         48206      47688        518       8177         10      11789
    -/+ buffers/cache:      35888      12317
    Swap:        15999       5378      10621
```

- VmSwap from /proc/*/status

  ```
  # grep "VmSwap:" /proc/*/status | awk '{swapped+=$2} END {print swapped/1024" MB"}'
  23.8438 MB

  # grep "VmSwap:" /proc/*/status | grep -v " 0 kB"
  /proc/1/status:VmSwap:        52 kB
  /proc/27714/status:VmSwap:           956 kB
  /proc/27718/status:VmSwap:           948 kB
  /proc/27722/status:VmSwap:           820 kB
  /proc/27723/status:VmSwap:           804 kB
  /proc/27724/status:VmSwap:           812 kB
  /proc/27725/status:VmSwap:           804 kB
  /proc/29636/status:VmSwap:           760 kB
  /proc/29640/status:VmSwap:           960 kB
  /proc/29642/status:VmSwap:          1948 kB
  /proc/29643/status:VmSwap:           936 kB
  /proc/29647/status:VmSwap:          1624 kB
  /proc/29649/status:VmSwap:           872 kB
  /proc/3750/status:VmSwap:            116 kB
  /proc/3770/status:VmSwap:            228 kB
  /proc/3790/status:VmSwap:            260 kB
  /proc/3810/status:VmSwap:            444 kB
  /proc/3823/status:VmSwap:            164 kB
  /proc/4022/status:VmSwap:           2296 kB
  /proc/4037/status:VmSwap:            640 kB
  /proc/4049/status:VmSwap:            572 kB
  /proc/4058/status:VmSwap:            592 kB
  /proc/4068/status:VmSwap:            260 kB
  /proc/4081/status:VmSwap:            192 kB
  /proc/4095/status:VmSwap:             56 kB
  /proc/4110/status:VmSwap:             76 kB
  /proc/4112/status:VmSwap:             80 kB
  /proc/4114/status:VmSwap:             76 kB
  /proc/4116/status:VmSwap:             80 kB
  /proc/4118/status:VmSwap:             80 kB
  /proc/4120/status:VmSwap:             76 kB
  /proc/4127/status:VmSwap:           2068 kB
  /proc/4128/status:VmSwap:           2068 kB
  /proc/7655/status:VmSwap:            312 kB
  /proc/7661/status:VmSwap:            380 kB
  /proc/905/status:VmSwap:             840 kB
  ```
- tmpfs

  ```
  # mount | grep tmpfs
  tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
  ```
- /proc/meminfo

  ```
  # cat /proc/meminfo           
  MemTotal:       49363344 kB
  MemFree:          700676 kB
  Buffers:           11000 kB
  Cached:         11822364 kB
  SwapCached:       522436 kB
  Active:         37945008 kB
  Inactive:        4986964 kB
  Active(anon):   35707220 kB
  Inactive(anon):  3720092 kB
  Active(file):    2237788 kB
  Inactive(file):  1266872 kB
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Mlocked:               0 kB
  SwapTotal:      16383992 kB
  SwapFree:       10875936 kB
  Dirty:            224072 kB
  Writeback:             0 kB
  AnonPages:      30580752 kB
  Mapped:         12218972 kB
  Shmem:           8328572 kB
  Slab:             270104 kB
  SReclaimable:     181768 kB
  SUnreclaim:        88336 kB
  KernelStack:        4256 kB
  PageTables:        91528 kB
  NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
  Bounce:                0 kB
  WritebackTmp:          0 kB
  CommitLimit:    41065664 kB
  Committed_AS:   49589524 kB
  VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
  VmallocUsed:     5203000 kB
  VmallocChunk:   34327589304 kB
  HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
  AnonHugePages:   5289984 kB
  HugePages_Total:       0
  HugePages_Free:        0
  HugePages_Rsvd:        0
  HugePages_Surp:        0
  Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
  DirectMap4k:    31952556 kB
  DirectMap2M:    17270784 kB
  DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
  ```

## EDIT:

Problem solved, I found an information that 1372500 pages of shared memory is swapped:

```
    # ipcs -mu

    ------ Shared Memory Status --------
    segments allocated 32
    pages allocated 2752532
    pages resident  1380020
    pages swapped   1372500
    Swap performance: 0 attempts     0 successes

    # getconf PAGESIZE
    4096
    # echo $((1372500*4096/1024/1024))
    5361
```

Comment: Instead of an edit, you could add your solution as an answer. This way anyone would know that this already has an answer before reading to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

**Swap usage per proccess**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o posix
set -u
SUM=0
OVERALL=0
for DIR in `find /proc/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex "^/proc/[0-9]+"` ; do
PID=`echo $DIR | cut -d / -f 3`
PROGNAME=`ps -p $PID -o comm --no-headers`
for SWAP in `grep Swap $DIR/smaps 2>/dev/null| awk '{ print $2 }'`
do
let SUM=$SUM+$SWAP
done
echo "PID=$PID - Swap used: $SUM - ($PROGNAME )"
let OVERALL=$OVERALL+$SUM
SUM=0
done
echo "Overall swap used: $OVERALL"
```

Comment: I tried it at the very beginning, but it only show memory used by processes:

        `# grep "VmSwap:" /proc/*/status | awk '{swapped+=$2} END {print swapped/1024" MB"}'
        23.8438 MB`

Answer (score 2):

## Problem solved:

I found out that 1372500 pages, of shared memory is swapped.
Size of the page is 4096 bytes.

```
# ipcs -mu

------ Shared Memory Status --------
segments allocated 32
pages allocated 2752532
pages resident  1380020
pages swapped   1372500
Swap performance: 0 attempts     0 successes

# getconf PAGESIZE
4096

# echo "$((1372500*4096/1024/1024)) MB"
5361 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux moves infrequently accessed memory to swap; it doesn't always matter whether you have free memory or not at the time, see this answer on a similar question at askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/159358

Answer (score 0):

I use this bash to see what processes in **swap** - `for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less`